# String array to char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

How I convert a String array to charArray?

I want to make a parking system, I had done the add, update part, and delete. But now there's some problem with delete, I can delete the data from my students data files, but when I remove a record from my students data file, I want to remove it from the parking data file as well.

For example, I have my data stored as data[1][8] as L1001, I want to convert it to charArray so that I know the first "1" is floor number one, and the last 2 digits is for slot.

Here is my sample data for students data:

```
2

TP000000
A
B
0111111111
Abcabc@gmail.com
Wav 2716
Sun Feb 15 19:04:06 SGT 2015
Sat May 16 19:04:06 SGT 2015
L1001

TP11
A
b
0123456789
oo99@hotmail.com
OCH99
Sun Feb 15 19:04:31 SGT 2015
Sat May 16 19:04:31 SGT 2015
L1002
```

And here's my sample data for parking space :

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Why char array? Why not just take substrings of the parking string?

Comment: Your answer in not crear

Comment: A good object-oriented approach would be not to work with chars manually, but to create class `ParkingLot` with constructor `ParkingLot(String  id)` and in that class have methods that access the needed parts of the id, like `ParkingLot.floor()` and `ParkingLot.slot()` so work with chars in parts of `id` would be done only in those methods.

Answer (score 0):

`"string".toCharArray()` method from [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true) answers your question.
From documentation refers that :

> a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this
>   string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character
>   sequence represented by this string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting you problem properly - why **TP037190** - this is for. But since you are trying to convert a `String` to char array, you may use the following technique.
First put your string in a `String` type variable `sampleString`. Then convert it to char array using the code snippet -

```
String sampleString = "SomeSampleString"; 
char[] charArray = sampleString.toCharArray();
```